# Arreglar un profile con CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo este código en html para maquetar un *upperheader* en la página de inicio. Mi problemática radica más que nada al momento de estilizar el profile.

```css
.body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.upperheader {
  float: right;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.Contact-Buttons {
  float: right;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #5baaeb;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #2449eb;
  width: 50px;
}

.dropdown-content li {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.profile-circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 39px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
  -moz-border-radius: 99em;
  border-radius: 99em;
  border: 2px solid #2449eb;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dropdown .badge {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: -60px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightsalmon;
  color: white;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

#notification {
  color: orange;
  font-style: bold;
  background: #ffd9b3
}

.notifications {
  background-color: #fff2e6;
  font-style: bold;
}

.imgbell {
  padding: 10px, 0, 0, 10px;
}

.lower {
  background-color: white;
}

.Navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.Navbar ul li {
  float: left;
  color: #070707;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
}

.Navbar li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: rgb(46, 44, 44);
}

.Navbar li.active {
  color: rgb(0, 102, 204);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class=upperheader>
    <div class="Contact-Buttons">
      <button class="btn" href=#>Contact us</button>
      <button class="btn" href=#>FAQ</button>
      <span class=label-ntf>You have notifications</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">                       
        <div class=clearfix>
          <img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-6/128/profile-male-circle2-512.png" class="profile-circle"/>
          <span class="badge">3</span>
        </div>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0; ">
        <ul>
          <li>MY PROFILE</li>
          <li>CHANGE PASSWORD</li>
          <li>CHANGE SECURITY QUESTIONS</li>
          <li>RATES/FEES INFORMATION</li>
          <li>BANK INFORMATION</li>
          <li id="notification"> <img class="imgbell" src=bell.png width="20" height="20"> Notifications</li>
          <li class="notifications">PASSWORD EXPIRE SOON </li>
          <li class="notifications">NEW CHARGEBACKS ARE ON FILE </li>
          <li class="notifications">NEW FUNDING ACTIVITIES ON YOUR ACCOUNT </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lower">
    <img src="payments.png" alt="logo de oltiva" width=400px height=150px>
    <div class="Navbar">
      <ul>
        <li class="active" href=#>HOME</li>
        <li>TRANSACTIONS</li>
        <li>CHARGEBACKS</li>
        <li>STATEMENTS</li>
        <li>EQUIPMENT/SUPPLIES</li>
        <li>DOCUMENTS</li>
        <li>REPORTS</li>
        <li>TICKET CENTER</li>
        <li>ADMINISTRATION</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Necesito algo como esto:

[image: Imagen de referencia]

Sin embargo, el resultado más cercano al que llegué fue a esto:

[image: Resultado]

¿Alguna idea o consejo sobre qué podría modificar en mi código CSS para que quede lo mas parecido a la imagen de referencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola podrías utilizar Bootstrap para ordenar un poco el código (yo lo usé para ordenar tus divs), te dejo el link a la [Documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) para que puedas revisarlo. No llegué a resolver algunos problemas del menú desplegable que tiene el icono pero te puede servir de base para continuar.

```css
    .body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color:lightgray;
}

.upperheader{
    float:right;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;

}
.Contact-Buttons{
    background: #e3dfdf;
}

.btn{
    background-color: #5baaeb;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100px;

  }

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;

  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color:  #2449eb;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;


  }

  .dropdown-content li{
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    list-style:none;
  }
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.profile-circle{
    width: 40px;
    height: 39px;

    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
    -moz-border-radius: 99em;
    border-radius: 99em;
    border: 2px solid #2449eb;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
 .dropdown .badge {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    left: -60px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:lightsalmon;
    color: white;

  }
.clearfix{

}
#notification{
    color:orange;
    font-style: bold;
    background: #ffd9b3

}
.notifications{
    background-color: #fff2e6;
    font-style: bold;
}

.imgbell{
    padding: 10px,0, 0,10px;
}
.lower{

   background-color:white;
}

.Navbar{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:white;
}

.Navbar ul li {
    float: left;
    color: #070707;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
}

.Navbar li:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
  color: rgb(46, 44, 44);
}

.Navbar li.active{
    color:  rgb(0, 102, 204);


}
.logo-imagen{
}

.label-ntf{
 background: #eeca79;
 height: 25px;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 margin: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 Contact-Buttons d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span class="label-ntf">You have notifications</span>
    <div class="botones">
     <button class="btn" href=#>Contact us</button>
                 <button class="btn" href=#>FAQ</button> 
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-12 dropdown d-flex justify-content-between">
    <img src="payments.png" alt="logo de oltiva" width=400px height=150px class="logo-imagen">
    <button class="dropbtn">
                    <div class=clearfix>
                        <img  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-6/128/profile-male-circle2-512.png" class="profile-circle"/>
                        <span class="badge">3</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown"  >  
                     <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0; ">
                       <ul>
                       <li>MY PROFILE</li>
                       <li>CHANGE PASSWORD</li>
                       <li>CHANGE SECURITY QUESTIONS</li>
                       <li>RATES/FEES INFORMATION</li>
                       <li>BANK INFORMATION</li>
                       <li id="notification"> <img  class="imgbell"src=bell.png width="20" height="20">  Notifications</li>
                       <li class="notifications">PASSWORD EXPIRE SOON </li>
                       <li class="notifications">NEW CHARGEBACKS ARE ON FILE </li>
                       <li class="notifications">NEW FUNDING ACTIVITIES ON YOUR ACCOUNT </li>
                   </ul>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                </button>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-12 lower">
    
                    <div class="Navbar">
                       <ul>
                            <li class="active" href=#>HOME</li>
                            <li>TRANSACTIONS</li>
                            <li>CHARGEBACKS</li>
                            <li >STATEMENTS</li>
                            <li>EQUIPMENT/SUPPLIES</li>
                            <li>DOCUMENTS</li>
                            <li>REPORTS</li>
                            <li>TICKET CENTER</li>
                            <li>ADMINISTRATION</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Espero sea de ayuda.

¿No has probado la clase de bootsTrap `.col-md-`?
Te dejo la documentación para que puedas leerla y puedas entenderla un poco más: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Lo que yo haría para éste caso sería:

```
<section class="container">
   <section class="row">
      <section class="col-md-10"
         <!-- Pega aquí tú código del perfil. -->
      <section>
      <section class="col-md-2"
         <!-- Pega aquí tú código del perfil donde está la foto. -->
      <section>
   <section>
<section>
```

Recuerda que en total tiene que sumar 12, entonces si en uno le colocas 10 en el otro le colocarás 2; por ende coloqué un col-md-10 y el otro col-md-2.